# How can I reload the message updates in the messages.properties using Grails Localization plugin?

Tags: grails

In Grails Localization plugin [documentation](https://grails.org/plugin/localizations), it says:

> If you distribute your finished application in the form of a war file, then unless the target application server unzips the war file on installation, the localizations plugin will be unable to automatically load (or subsequently 'import') the properties files from within the war file.

In order to walk around to reload all the message updates using war, I use the following code in `BootStrap.groovy`.

```
import org.grails.plugins.localization.Localization

class BootStrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->
        Localization.reload()
    }
}
```

This code does help me that whenever the app deploys to a Tomcat server, the message updates will apply. But as more and more releases get deployed, the localization table's id number increases automatically.

So I tried "truncate table" in my code to resolve the issue. In `BootStrap.groovy`:

```
import org.grails.plugins.localization.Localization

class BootStrap {
    def sessionFactory
    def init = { servletContext ->
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery('truncate table localization').executeUpdate()
        Localization.load()
    }
}
```

Using this code leads the `run-app` fails, because sometime, the `truncate table` happens in the middle of the load process, not before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localization plugin has a `LocalizationsBootStrap.groovy`. Writing code in `BootStrap.groovy` leads to a race between two of the BootStrap files.

We can just **do nothing** in the `BootStrap.groovy`,but **override** the `LocalizationsBootStrap.groovy` by createing it under `conf`:

```
import org.grails.plugins.localization.*
class LocalizationsBootStrap {
    def sessionFactory
    def init = { servletContext ->
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery('truncate table localization').executeUpdate()
        Localization.load()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to execute it as a thread and force waiting for the end of that process?